# Loading video via jQuery makes page not functional

Tags: jquery, youtube-javascript-api, jquery-load

I got this weird trouble with my jQuery code. The few lines that makes Youtube video load makes other functions disabled. I cant figure out what is happening.

This function is causing it:

```
    function loadVideo(videoID) {
    alert(videoID);

  if(ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
  }
}
}
```

If I just //comment the part with ytplayer, the page starts working again.

This is the whole code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
  document.getElementById(elmId).innerHTML = value;
}

function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
  alert("An error occured of type:" + errorCode);
}

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
}

function loadPlayer() {
  var videoID = "ylLzyHk54Z0"
  var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
  var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
  swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + 
                     "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", 
                     "videoDiv", "640", "360", "9", null, null, params, atts);
}
$(window).load(function(){
function loadVideo(videoID) {
    alert(videoID);

  if(ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
  }
}
}

function changeDescription(description){
    $('#descriptionBox p').text(description);
}

$(".videoLink").on("click", function () {
    var videoId = $(this).data('video'),
        description = $(this).data('description');
    loadVideo(videoID);
    changeDescription(description);

});

function _run() {
  loadPlayer();
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(_run);


});

</script>
```

I will be really glad if you could help me, I am looking way too long.